# Excel Nested IF Statements For Column Comparison

Tags: excel

I have two columns (E, F) reading in data from two other worksheets. The goal is to identify a value that may exist only in 1 or both of the referenced worksheets.

I want to compare the values between each row in column E against column F knowing that either may contain "0":

`IF E39 <> 0 AND F39 = 0 THEN +E39 
ELSE IF E39 = 0 AND F39 <> 0 THEN +F39 
ELSE IF E39 <> 0 AND F39 <> 0 THEN (EXACT(E39,F39), +E39, "Mismatch")
ELSE E39 = 0 AND F39 = 0 THEN "Value not found"`

Addtional Info:

I have cell E3 keying off of cell A3 value to find a Coding Values:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FinalVersion!$A3,worksheet1!$A$2:$D$11696,4,FALSE),0)
```

I have cell F3 doing the exact same thing but against a different worksheet:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FinalVersion!$A3,worksheet2!$A$2:$D$1000,4,FALSE),0)
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? If it were SQL, I could easily code, but sadly I'm stumbling within Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
=IF(AND(E39=0,F39=0),"Value not found",IF(AND(E39<>0,F39<>0),IF(E39<>F39,"Mismatch",E39),E39+F39))
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast! You're the Guru of Excel! Thanks!

Comment: FYI, your solution is quite educational. I've been spending the past 15 minutes studying it and finally get why you're doing it in the order you are. Thanks again.